# Missing Function Hint in Status Bar in R Windows

Tags: r

When I work on the latest version of R on MacOS (10.3.3), the status bar displays Function Hints showing the argument list of function name I have typed in console.

For eg. if I type `> c(`, the status-bar shows `c(..., recursive = FALSE)`.

This feature seems to be missing with the Windows console of R. How to get Function Hints feature in R for Windows?

Comment: try using [RStudio](http://www.rstudio.com) ?

Comment: Same issue with RStudio .
I want an auto hint which keeps showing based on what function name you type on the command prompt, not another function. That solution is obvious and known.

Comment: I'm using RStudio-0.99.441, and it is giving function hints *for most functions*. Conspicuously quiet are simpler functions like `c()`, but most seem to be working fine. It doesn't appear in the statusbar, rather as a pop-up and tooltip. I get nothing on Windows Rgui (*R*-3.2.0), and though I rarely open it, I don't recall ever seeing it before. Not a huge help so much as "I've never seen it any other way" (on Windows). (Regardless, this is not a programming question so much as an application question.)

Comment: I prefer R as it is, over RStudio. Is there an option of function hints for R in Windows like it is in Mac ?